# Given a top left location and center location find bottom right location

Tags: coordinates

If I have a rectangle, in which top left point corresponds to a specific location `(lat1, lng1)` and center corresponds to another location `(lat2, lng2)`, how can I find to which location corresponds bottom right point?

I will try to illustrate now what I mean. I have a rectangle (by rectangle I mean an actual map area, a randomly zoomed-in part of Mercator projection) (say `x` in width and `y` in height) with `L` point in top left, `M` point in the center and `R` point in the bottom right:

```
L----------------------+
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|          M           |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
+----------------------R
```

`L(0, 0)` or `L(-x/2, y/2)` (whichever coordinate system you prefer) corresponds to `(lat1, lng1)` and `M` corresponds to `(lat2, lng2)` which are known. Is it possible to find `(lat3, lng3)` of `R` from the given data? It is safe to assume that `lat1 > lat2` and `lng1 < lng2` always.

I have tried adjusting [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#midpoint) formula (which is basically the inverse of my task) to solve the problem, but could not come to solvable equation, and the resulting system did not look easily solvable.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you provide more properties of your "rectangle" ? Is your center the projection of the center of gravity, do you want the center to separate two parts with the same area ?

Comment: You're starting out wrong if the coordinates are "lat,lng", since latitude is a Y value. Spherical rectangles are strange ducks, and spheroidal rectangles are stranger still. Please **edit** the question to specify the range of potential latitudes involved. Your "rectangles" will need to look like parallelograms.

Comment: @radouxju updated the question

Comment: @Vince updated the question

Comment: You need to use optimisation procedure (scipy) to solve it numerically. Long,lat are 2 unknowns parameters to optimize, distance to M point is objective function to find a minimum of

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing information, you should just be able to find the difference b/w your top left and center coordinates, then double that difference to get the bottom right coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! While this approach would work with an acceptable error on higher zoom levels, it will not work on smaller zoom levels. For example, if L is `(69.468616; -42.179178)` and M is `(52.376142, 4.908439)` then R's latitude would be `51.996056`, while the actual location would have latitude around `54`.